# Best Practise: presenting some data (making a report) from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have many SQL Server databases, each with a few tables containing important (from my point of view) information. I check the data (retrieving for example maximum or minimum value) within those tables using T-SQL queries.

Since I don't want to create *views* for each of the databases, I'm thinking about most convenient, easier and simply the best way to prepare summary which will be updating each time when opened.

The output file (or web page) will be used internally within technical team. All members can log into database using Windows authentication.

My idea was:

1. Excel + dynamic T-SQL --> I want to connect to database and execute T-SQL (cursor will go through all database names)
2. PowerShell (showing table using Out-GridView cmdlet)
3. PHP - first I will ask about all database names (executing `select name from`sys.databases` and then execute query for each DB)

What is in your opinion best way? Do you have any better (from programmers point of view) way of getting such report/data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSRS Reports .You have the options of exporting the report data  to several formats such as pdf ,excel ,word .You can create a dataset for all your database .Since you are interested in showing aggregation and summation of values ,SSRS reports will be pretty useful in these cases .

Comment: +1. Funny how someone working with many sql databases does not know there is a full report generator in ;) Right tools for the right jobs, guys ;)

Comment: Little bit knowledge of Business Intelligence ( MSBI Stack ) will always be useful to any DBA ..!!